# Concurrent execution/Re-entrant /ThreadSafe/?

Tags: multithreading, reentrancy

I read many answers given here for questions related to thread safety, re-entrancy, but when i think about them, some more questions came to mind, hence this question/s.

1.) I have one executable program say some *.exe. If i run this program on command prompt, and while it is executing, i run the same program on another command prompt, then in what conditions the results could be corrupted, i.e. should the code of this program be re-entrant or it should be thread safe alone?

2.) While defining re-entrancy, we say that the routine can be re-entered while it is already running, in what situations the function can be re-entered (apart from being recursive routine, i am not talking recursive execution here). There has to be some thread to execute the same code again, or how can that function be entered again?

3.) In a practical case, will two threads execute same code, i.e. perform same functionality. I thought the idea of multi-threading is to execute different functionality, concurrently(on different cores/processors).

Sorry if these queries seem different, but they all occured to me, same time when i read about the threadsafe Vs reentrant post on SO, hence i put them together.

Any pointers, reading material will be appreciated.

thanks,

-AD.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain these, in order:

1. Each program runs in its own process, and gets its own isolated memory space.  You don't have to worry about thread safety in this situation.  (However, if the processes are both accessing some other shared resource, such as a file, you may have different issues.  For example, process 1 may "lock" the data file, preventing process 2 from being able to open it).
2. The idea here is that two threads may try to run the same routine at the same time.  This is not always valid - it takes special care to define a class or a process in a way that multiple threads can use the same instance of the same class, or the same static function, without errors occurring.  This typically requires synchronization in the class.
3. Two threads often execute the same code.  There are two different conceptual ways to parition your work when threading.  You can either think in terms of **tasks** - ie: one thread does task A while another does task B.  Alternatively, you can think in terms of decomposing the the problem based on **data**.  In this case, you work with a large collection, and each element is processed using the same routine, but the processing happens in parallel.  For more info, you can read this blog post I wrote on [Decomposition for Parallelism](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/19/parallelism-in-net-part-1-decomposition/).

Comment: @goldenmean: No problem.  That series (in progress) is very .NET oriented, but the decomposition post is language-neutral, so I thought it might help explain that issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Two processes cannot share memory.  So thread-safety is moot here.
2. Re-entrancy means that a method can be safely executed by two threads at the same time.  This doesn't require recursion - threads are separate units of execution, and there is nothing keeping them both from attempting to run the same method simultaneously.
3. The benefits to threading can happen in two ways.  One is when you perform different types of operations concurrently (like running cpu-intensive code and I/O-intensive code at the ame time).  The other is when you can divide up a long-running operation among multiple processors.  In this latter case, two threads may be executing the same function at the same time on different input data sets.

Comment: That is not reentrancy: reentrancy is nothing more than ability of some function/method of being executed concurrently several times and still returning valid value for it's input parameters.

Comment: Yes, that is true, although it is not correct to say "that is not reentrancy".  There are two definitions of the word, which I didn't realize.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I strongly suggest you to look at some basic stuffs of computer system, especially how a process/thread is executing on CPU and scheduled by operating system. For example, virtual address, context switching, process/thread concepts(e.g., each thread has its own stack and register vectors while heap is shared by threads. A thread is an execution and scheduling unit, so it maintains control flow of code..) and so on. All of the questions are related to understanding *how your program is actually working on CPU*

1) and 2) are already answered.

3) Multithreading is just *concurrent* execution of any arbitrary thread. The same code can be executed by multiple threads. These threads can share some data, and even can make data races which are very hard to find. Of course, many times threads are executing separate code(we say it as thread-level parallelism).

In this context, I have used *concurrent* as two meaning: (a) in a single processor, multiple threads are sharing a single physical processor, but operating system gives a sort of illusion that threads are running concurrently. (b) In a multicore, yes, physically two or more threads can be executed concurrently.

Having concrete understanding of concurrent/parallel execution takes quite long time. But, you already have a solid understanding!